# Angularjs Action Tooltip service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to ask you if anyone knows how to make this kind of action tooltip in angularjs ? [image: AlertToolTip]

Comment: do u think that is a good practise to get confirmation in tool tip??

Comment: you can try https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip the tooltip is customizable.

Comment: @Aravind I got this design from a client

Comment: Add some code which you have tried

Comment: @Aravind yes I am?

Comment: @Aravind my bad, I forgot. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: cool. if anything needed connect with me in FB @ aravind2109. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!! Your **Tool Tip with Alert** , as I said earlier this is not a good practise to have decision making DOM elements in the tool tip. But, still you can use this,

Include these HTML in your page that is going to contain the tooltip

```
var app = angular.module("alert", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function(e) {
  e.name = "World"
}]), app.directive("alertTooltip", ["$compile", function(e) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      alertTooltipScope: "="
    },
    link: function(n, o, t) {
      var i = t.alertTooltip;
      n.hidden = !0;
      var a = angular.element("<div ng-hide='hidden'>");
      a.append("<div ng-include='\"" + i + "\"'></div>"), o.parent().append(a), o.on("mouseenter", function() {
        n.hidden = !1, n.$digest()
      }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        n.hidden = !0, n.$digest()
      });
      var l = n.$new(!0);
      angular.extend(l, n.alertTooltipScope), e(a.contents())(l), e(a)(n)
    }
  }
}]);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VdopPkgiyktZUiv8WEqo?p=preview)